# Wordpress yoast seo plugin - parse snippet var in meta description

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags, yoast

I am using this function to get the yoast meta description

```
$metadesc = get_post_meta( $id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true );
```

But it is returning the snippet variable.

```
From transitional styles %%title%% with soft color palettes to bold
```

How can I parse that %%variable%%?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is how I parsed the snippets in case anyone else needs to know

```
$id = get_the_ID();

$post         = get_post( $id, ARRAY_A );
$yoast_title = get_post_meta( $id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true );
$yoast_desc = get_post_meta( $id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true );

$metatitle_val = wpseo_replace_vars($yoast_title, $post );
$metatitle_val = apply_filters( 'wpseo_title', $metatitle_val );

$metadesc_val = wpseo_replace_vars($yoast_desc, $post );
$metadesc_val = apply_filters( 'wpseo_metadesc', $metadesc_val );

echo $metatitle_val;
echo "<br>";
echo $metadesc_val;
```